# How can I count users that have travelled in a given period and have travelled in the year before?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I have a table with all bookings and user data from a travel agency and would like to find out what follows:

A traveller can have multiple records in the table
A traveller is identified by the dedup column

I would like to find out for every month of each year, how many of the travellers that travelled in that month, traveled the year before (How can I find the count of travellers for a given month and year that have travelled in the year before)

Is it possible to have a similar result table with an extra column holding the count of records that have travelled the year before?

I'm new to SQL but eager to learn and have been triïng for 2 days only came as far as getting a count of all unique travellers for each month and year using this query:

```
SELECT BookingYear, BookingMonth, COUNT( DISTINCT (Dedup) ) 
AS  'Count of travellers'
FROM DATA
GROUP BY BookingYear, BookingMonth
```

resulting in this dataset:

```
+-------------+--------------+---------------------+
| BookingYear | BookingMonth | Count of travellers |
+-------------+--------------+---------------------+
|        2009 |           11 |                 384 |
|        2009 |           12 |                1084 |
|        2010 |            1 |                4641 |
|        2010 |            2 |                1922 |
|        2010 |            3 |                1453 |
|        2010 |            4 |                1032 |
|        2010 |            5 |                 967 |
|        2010 |            6 |                1095 |
|        2010 |            7 |                2490 |
|        2010 |            8 |                2425 |
|        2010 |            9 |                 920 |
|        2010 |           10 |                 213 |
|        2010 |           11 |                1140 |
|        2010 |           12 |                1981 |
|        2011 |            1 |                3514 |
|        2011 |            2 |                1284 |
|        2011 |            3 |                1424 |
|        2011 |            4 |                 867 |
|        2011 |            5 |                1395 |
|        2011 |            6 |                1318 |
|        2011 |            7 |                3182 |
|        2011 |            8 |                2491 |
|        2011 |            9 |                1119 |
|        2011 |           10 |                 144 |
|        2011 |           11 |                1937 |
|        2011 |           12 |                3092 |
|        2012 |            1 |                4752 |
|        2012 |            2 |                1266 |
|        2012 |            3 |                 949 |
|        2012 |            4 |                1107 |
|        2012 |            5 |                1352 |
|        2012 |            6 |                1454 |
|        2012 |            7 |                3365 |
|        2012 |            8 |                1590 |
|        2012 |            9 |                 656 |
|        2012 |           10 |                 209 |
|        2012 |           11 |                2445 |
|        2012 |           12 |                3769 |
|        2013 |            1 |                7570 |
|        2013 |            2 |                4646 |
|        2013 |            3 |                2329 |
|        2013 |            4 |                2666 |
|        2013 |            5 |                2506 |
|        2013 |            6 |                1973 |
|        2013 |            7 |                3336 |
|        2013 |            8 |                2229 |
|        2013 |            9 |                 398 |
+-------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

This is the table structure:

```
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BookingCode          | int(15)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Dedup                | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BookToDep            | int(4)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BookingYear          | int(4)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BookingMonth         | int(2)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DepartureYear        | int(4)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DepartureMonth       | int(2)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| GroupCount           | int(3)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Duration             | int(3)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Gender               | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Age                  | int(3)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Birthdate            | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Country              | varchar(2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| AccoCountry          | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| AccoRegion           | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| AccoDestination      | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RevenueEntireBooking | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is a excerpt of the data:

```
+-------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+------------+----------+--------+------+---------------------+---------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| BookingCode | Dedup                   | BookToDep | BookingYear | BookingMonth | DepartureYear | DepartureMonth | GroupCount | Duration | Gender | Age  | Birthdate           | Country | AccoCountry | AccoRegion      | AccoDestination | RevenueEntireBooking |
+-------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+------------+----------+--------+------+---------------------+---------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
|      948757 | EMMENROCUS14390         |       188 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          7 |        8 | M      |   73 | 1939-05-25 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Lara            |              4136.00 |
|      948757 | EMMENANTONETTA28626     |       188 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          7 |        8 | F      |   34 | 1978-05-16 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Lara            |              4136.00 |
|      948757 | HEESTERSWESLEY34719     |       188 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          7 |        8 | M      |   17 | 1995-01-20 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Lara            |              4136.00 |
|      948757 | EMMENHUBERDINA25710     |       188 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          7 |        8 | F      |   42 | 1970-05-22 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Lara            |              4136.00 |
|      948757 | HEESTERSANTHONY25917    |       188 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          7 |        8 | M      |   41 | 1970-12-15 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Lara            |              4136.00 |
|      948757 | VANDERHOEVENRONALD27069 |       188 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          7 |        8 | M      |   38 | 1974-02-09 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Lara            |              4136.00 |
|      948757 | HEESTERSMIRTHE35781     |       188 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          7 |        8 | C      |   14 | 1997-12-17 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Lara            |              4136.00 |
|      949055 | BOGERSPATRICK26350      |       184 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          4 |       11 | M      |   40 | 1972-02-21 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Belek           |              1922.00 |
|      949055 | BOGERSJORDI37246        |       184 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          4 |       11 | C      |   10 | 2001-12-21 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Belek           |              1922.00 |
|      949055 | DEBREEESTHER25664       |       184 |        2009 |           11 |          2010 |              5 |          4 |       11 | F      |   42 | 1970-04-06 00:00:00 | NL      | Turkije     | Turkse  Riviera | Belek           |              1922.00 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+------------+----------+--------+------+---------------------+---------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: So is it for SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL Server:

```
with cte as (
    select 
       d.BookingYear, d.BookingMonth, count(distinct(d.Dedup)) as [Count of travellers]
    from DATA as d
    group by d.BookingYear, d.BookingMonth
)
select
    c.BookingYear, c.BookingMonth,
    c.[Count of travellers],
    isnull(c2.[Count of travellers], 0) as [Count of travellers previous year]
from cte as c
    left outer join cte as c2 on
        c2.BookingMonth = c.BookingMonth and c2.BookingYear = c1.BookingYear - 1
```

For MySQL you could use:

```
    select 
        d.BookingYear, d.BookingMonth,
        count(distinct(d.Dedup)) as [Count of travellers],
        count(distinct(d2.Dedup)) as [Count of travellers previous year]
    from DATA as d
        left outer join DATA as d2 on 
           d2.BookingMonth = d.BookingMonth and d2.BookingYear = d1.BookingYear - 1
    group by d.BookingYear, d.BookingMonth
```

Comment: Thank you Roman, I'm using mysql though (first thing in the question ;-), sorry for your effort! A vote would be much appreciated ;-)

Comment: txs Roman, I had to change a few things square brackets to ' and d2 to d but it is running :) I have 95K records so I can imagine it will take some time to run?